# Preventing multiple runs of a cell in google colaboratory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

Here is I define `run_once` cell magic in order to prevent multiple output in same code in google colaboratory. If it's happen while code is not changed, it will display history output without actual computation like first run.

```
#@title Mendefinisikan Fungsi `run_once`
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from google.colab import output
from hashlib import sha1
import time
import os

@register_cell_magic
def run_once(line: str, cell: str):
  """
  This is a custom cell magic command in order to prevent multiple runs, so the cell must be run once for every runtime.
  If the cell has already run before, then it will display the history output.
  Usage: %%run_once
  """
  try:

    # Argument of this magic cell is specifying tracker directory
    tracker_dir = line
    if len(tracker_dir) == 0:
      tracker_dir = './.run_once' # Set default if not specified.

    # Create input-output tracker directory
    if not os.path.exists(tracker_dir):
      os.makedirs(tracker_dir)

    # Get cell id by cell changes with SHA-1 as identifier
    cell_id = sha1(cell.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    # Check wether cell_id.html already exists. (Imply the cell already run)
    if os.path.exists(f'{tracker_dir}/{cell_id}.html'):
      with open(f'{tracker_dir}/{cell_id}.html', 'r') as file_cell_output:
        html_output = file_cell_output.read()
      last_created = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC+00', time.gmtime(os.path.getctime(f'{tracker_dir}/{cell_id}.html')))
      print(f'This cell ({cell_id}) already ran before, last run was:', last_created, ', displaying history output...\n')
      display(HTML(html_output))
      return

    # Execute actual code.
    exec(cell, globals(), locals())

    # After code has executed, it will contains some output. Save it!
    html_output = output.eval_js('document.getElementById("output-area").innerHTML;')
    with open(f'{tracker_dir}/{cell_id}.html', 'w') as file_cell_output:
      file_cell_output.write(html_output)

    # Also save the cell code for archive purpose
    with open(f'{tracker_dir}/{cell_id}.cell.py', 'w') as file_cell_input:
      file_cell_input.write(cell)

  except Exception as e:
    print(f"run_once error: {str(e)}")
```

Usage example:

```
%%run_once

print("This is  an example of cell that can't be runs multiple times")
```

But I have problem where it's not a python syntax such as shell command

```
%%run_once

!ls current_directory
```

Returning:

```
run_once error: invalid syntax (<string>, line 2)
```

Also it seems doesn't work to define global variable:

```
#CELL A
%%run_once

myvar = 5
```

While when I `print(myvar)` in cell B it will say `myvar` not defined. But it works vice versa where I define `myvar` without magic cell `run_once` in a cell and then print the `myvar` in a cell that in mode `run_once`

I suspect because it's using `exec`.

For more screenshosts about its usage I provide the github link
[enter link description here](https://github.com/wawan-ikhwan/run-once-colab)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `exec(cell)` with `get_ipython.run_cell(cell)`

Therefore the overall magic cell definition will looks like this:

```
#@title Mendefinisikan Fungsi `run_once`
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from google.colab import output
from hashlib import sha1
import time
import os

@register_cell_magic
def run_once(line: str, cell: str):
  """
  This is a custom cell magic command in order to prevent multiple runs, so the cell must be run once for every runtime.
  If the cell has already run before, then it will display the history output.
  Usage: %%run_once
  """
  try:

    # Argument of this magic cell is specifying tracker directory
    tracker_dir = line
    if len(tracker_dir) == 0:
      tracker_dir = './.run_once' # Set default if not specified.

    # Create input-output tracker directory
    if not os.path.exists(tracker_dir):
      os.makedirs(tracker_dir)

    # Get cell id by cell changes with SHA-1 as identifier
    cell_id = sha1(cell.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    # Check wether cell_id.html already exists. (Imply the cell already run)
    if os.path.exists(f'{tracker_dir}/{cell_id}.html'):
      with open(f'{tracker_dir}/{cell_id}.html', 'r') as file_cell_output:
        html_output = file_cell_output.read()
      last_created = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC+00', time.gmtime(os.path.getctime(f'{tracker_dir}/{cell_id}.html')))
      print(f'This cell ({cell_id}) already ran before, last run was:', last_created, ', displaying history output:\n')
      display(HTML(html_output))
      return

    # Actual computation
    get_ipython().run_cell(cell)

    # After code has executed, it will contains some output. Save it!
    html_output = output.eval_js('document.getElementById("output-area").innerHTML;')
    with open(f'{tracker_dir}/{cell_id}.html', 'w') as file_cell_output:
      file_cell_output.write(html_output)

    # Also save the cell code for archive purpose
    with open(f'{tracker_dir}/{cell_id}.cell.py', 'w') as file_cell_input:
      file_cell_input.write(cell)

  except Exception as e:
    print(f"run_once error: {str(e)}")
```

Now it's support defining global variable through it, also it now support shell command such as `!ls`.